# Open android project from parent module on studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I clone an android project from git hub, and while open that project from android studio, its project module looks like this

[image]

But it shows the android module as empty. The problem I detected is I opened the parent folder in android studio and the project is on its child folder.
How can I resolve this problem, I cloned the parent folder from git hub. if I open the child folder directly from android studio,then android module also loading,but the git hub connection lost.Please help.

Suppose I clone project from https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus.git ,How can I open each project on android studio?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an eclipse project. You can't directly open it in android studio. You need to import it File->New->import project